# How to change method comments after a modification

Tags: php, aptana, phpdoc

I am using aptana editor which automatically adds phpdoc in implementation class's method like

```
/**
* (non-PHPdoc)
@see trunk/library/Storage_interface::get()
*/
```

As you can see, Storage_interface is the main interface class. Now lets say there is a change in interface class name. How can I reflect modified name in all implemented methods comments? Is there any way other than manual update?

Comment: I would try deleting the phpdoc and and then regenerating it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, this autopopulation of the @see tag in that docblock is the result of this empty docblock being auto-generated above the same named method (get()) of this child class / implementor class.  As such, if you were to change the method name in the parent class or the interface, then you MUST also change the method name in the code here.  So, it's still up to you to update this docblock with the new method name in the @see link.

Comment: hmm.. so there are no other options as such other than manually updating a docblock in such scenarios.

Comment: Correct CM... but again, in this scenario of changing the method name in the parent that you are overriding in the method you're looking at, you have to manually change the method name in your own code right in front of you.  So, you are already right there at the docblock in question, so you can manually update the class name referenced by the @-see tag.  Granted, if you delete the docblock and then begin writing it again, its autopopulation will pick up the correct name then.

Comment: I suppose the "automation" that would result from delete-and-restart the docblock on this child class's method could be perceived as having some benefit.  At a minimum, it does create the @see tag with a fully pathed parent method string...